# A soccer squad contains $3$ goalkeepers, $7$ defenders, $9$ midfielders and $4$ forwards.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A soccer squad contains $3$ goalkeepers, $7$ defenders, $9$ midfielders and $4$ forwards.

So I understood the first part of the question:

$(i)$ In how many ways can a team of $1$ goalkeeper, $4$ defenders, $4$ midfielders, and $2$ forwards be chosen from this squad?

**Answer:** $ \binom31 \cdot \binom74 \cdot \binom94 \cdot \binom42$

However, I don't quite understand how to do the next bit:

$(ii)$ Two of the defenders refuse to play together. In how many ways can a team be chosen that contains at most one of these two defenders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to notice is that we can easily compute the number of teams where these two defenders *do* play together: just change the ${7\choose 4}$ to ${5\choose 2}$. Then we can subtract this from what you found in the first part to get the answer to the second.

Answer (score 1):

Remaining answer remains same only the part of defenders is that 1) neither of the two  defenders is in team so we have ${5\choose 4}$ now if one of them is in the team so he is already selected . Now we have to select only $3$ from $5$,as the player who refused won't play so we have $1.{5\choose 3}$ this can be done for the players in reverse way so again $1.{5\choose 3}$ hence total ways are ${3\choose 1}.({5\choose 4}+2.{5\choose 3}).{9\choose 4}.{4\choose 2}$

Comment: Your answer is correct.  However, for clarity, no defender should be changed to neither defender.